# Running bats tests from another bash function yields: `./main.sh: line 21: 1..3: command not found`

Tags: bash, function, testing, bats-core

### Context

While running some `bats` tests after an installation, I noticed that the tests throw an error when I run `bats` test files from a different function in the same file `main.sh`. The tests work works when executed directly with:

```
./test/libs/bats/bin/bats test/test_install_git_postsetup.bats
```

from the first function `run_prompt_user_choice()` that is executed in `main.sh`. However when I copy that command and put it in:

```
function run_some_test() {
    ./test/libs/bats/bin/bats test/test_install_git_postsetup.bats
}
```

and call that function from inside `run_prompt_user_choice()` with command: `($run_some_tests)`, it throws error: `./main.sh: line 21: 1..3: command not found`.

### Code

The code of the `main.sh` consists of:

```
#!/bin/bash
. src/ask_user_choice.sh

function run_some_test() {
    ./test/libs/bats/bin/bats test/test_install_git_postsetup.bats
}

function run_prompt_user_choice() { 
    # install selected packages.
    $(install_user_choices)
    
    # test selected packages using a function.
    $(run_some_test)
    
    # Run the github test file directly
    ./test/libs/bats/bin/bats test/test_install_git_postsetup.bats
}
run_prompt_user_choice "$@"
```

### Output

The output of running `sudo ./main.sh` is:

```
./main.sh: line 21: 1..3: command not found
 ✓ running the apt update function in some file and verifying log output.
 ✓ running the apt upgrade function in some file and verifying log output.
 ✓ running the apt install git function in some file and verifying log output.

3 tests, 0 failures
```

### Question

How could I run those tests from an arbitrary function that is called by the `run_prompt_user_choice()` function?

Comment: `1..3` isn't anywhere in your code, and you aren't showing us sample input where it comes from.

Comment: That said, in general, you should run `run_some_test`, **not** `$(run_some_test)`; and `install_user_choices`, **not** `$(install_user_choices)`.

Comment: When you put `$(...)` around your command, you're reading the _output_ of that command... and then running that output as another command! It would be very unusual for that to do something helpful (especially since it doesn't parse that output the way commands are usually parsed, but instead processes in a manner subject to all the pitfalls/caveats discussed in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) discussing why commands shouldn't be stored in strings).

Comment: Beyond that, if you want to narrow down a specific issue, I'd strongly suggest using `set -x` to enable trace logging to help you figure out exactly where things are first behaving in an unexpected way, so you can build a more narrow/specific question around that.

Comment: As another aside, the `function` keyword is generally best avoided -- it's an artifact of compatibility with pre-POSIX ksh, which is to say, ksh releases from the 1980s. Ever since the 1991 publication of POSIX.2, `myfunc() {` is the correct way to define a function, with no `function` before it; see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete entries in both first and third tables.

Comment: Re: answers being included in questions, see [Is it OK for users to edit the accepted answer into their question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262806/is-it-ok-for-users-to-edit-the-accepted-answer-into-their-question); and [Is it acceptable to answer a closed question by editing the answer into the question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404545/is-it-acceptable-to-answer-a-closed-question-by-editing-the-answer-into-the-ques)

Comment: Thank you! The answer to the question was, as mentioned by @CharlesDuffy to call the function with `run_some_test` instead of `$(run_some_test)`.